# Hide Tier Prices for Not Logged In - Catalog Permissions Extension Mangeto

Tags: php, magento

I'm using the Catalog Permissions extension by aheadWorks to hide pricing for customers who are not logged in. However, I need to be able to hide the tier pricing as well. What would the PHP code be for this and what file would I put it in?

Answer (score 0):

Tier pricing is great, but you don’t want to display every price to every customer. To show tiered pricing to logged in visitors only, go to: `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml`

On this file, add this PHP function

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
```

The above function should be added before the following piece of code

```
<?php if (count($_tierPrices) > 0): ?>
```

Then add this code at the end.

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What if the function should only be for one category?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own layout file and inside  set your own template file with the required condition.

```
   <catalog_product_view>
       <reference name="core_reference_name">
          <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>yournamespace/catalog/product/view.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>      
   </catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide price on Category list page, Product view page, and Compare pop up.
Override the default Magento files by basic module.

Create folder and file for basic module Hideproductprice

```
app/etc/modules/Hideproductprice_Hideproductprice.xml
app/code/local/Hideproductprice/Hideproductprice/controllers/IndexController.php
app/code/local/Hideproductprice/Hideproductprice/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/Hideproductprice/Hideproductprice/Block/Index.php

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/hideproductprice.xml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/hideproductprice/price.phtml
```

1: add the following code your custom module layout file

```
(app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/hideproductprice.xml)
<default>
        <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>hideproductprice/price.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>grouped</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>hideproductprice/price.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>configurable</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>hideproductprice/price.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>virtual</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>hideproductprice/price.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundled</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>hideproductprice/price.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
  </default>
```

2: Then copy the default 'price.phtml' and place it in the specified location (in our case 'hideproductprice/price.phtml'). And the place the following code on top of it.

```
<?php
    if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        echo '<span class="login_for_price"><b>Login to See Price</b></span><br>';
        return;
    }
    ?>
```

Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Orders_Grid

```
/* adding customer name section */       
        $customerFirstNameAttr = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->getResource()->getAttribute('firstname');
        $collection->getSelect()
                            ->joinLeft(
                                array('cusFirstnameTb' => $customerFirstNameAttr->getBackend()->getTable()),
                                'main_table.customer_id = cusFirstnameTb.entity_id AND cusFirstnameTb.attribute_id = '.$customerFirstNameAttr->getId(). ' AND cusFirstnameTb.entity_type_id = '.Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->getResource()->getTypeId(),
                                array('customer_name' =>'cusFirstnameTb.value')
                            ); 
            /* end adding customer name section */
```